# Chart.js place y value position and its x-label position relative to the x-value

Tags: chart.js

Is it possible for me to supply a chart.js chart with a list of Y values that have a corresponding label/X value and place them vertically and horizontally relative to their own value.

For example: I have a list of values at a certain time (unix timestamp) that I want to show on a chart, with its Y value positioned relative, but also its horizontal position and its label relative on the x-scale.

[image: The Y values and its labels are both automatically positioned according to their values]

At this moment it always spaces out my labels, completely over the entire x axis, at equal distances, without taking into account the values of the labels itself. Is there way to automatically accomplish this with chart.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line or scatter chart will do the job.  The main criteria is that the data is a series of x and y coordinates.  Each point in the array is in the form:

```
{
  x: xValue,
  y: yValue
}
```

See http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/scatter/basic.html

[here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/microMerlin/9t2jjwLb/) that reproduces your image.